# regex match number not in latex math mode

Tags: regex, latex

I have a statement like this:

```
"there is a LaTex is ${ \\frac{123}{456} }$
and a pure number 789 and another LaTex ${ 9^{n+1} }$"`
```

I need a regex to get the number **789**, not numbers inside math mode.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this regex:

```
/(?:^|\}\$)(?:.(?!\$\{))*?(\d+)/
```

Explanation:

```
(?:        # a non-capturing group
  ^|\}\$   # either the beginning of the string, or a "}$"
)          # this will make sure we're not currently in a LaTeX thingy

(?:        # another non-capturing group
  .        # any character
  (?!\$\{) # not followed by a "${" (make sure we don't go into a LaTeX thingy)
)*?        # repeated zero or more times

(\d+)      # the number that you want!
```

I'm assuming that your LaTeX will be well-formed; i.e. you won't have a string like `${ 123 }$ }$ 456 ${ 789 }$` with unmatched brackets.

Try it:

```js
var regex = /(?:^|\}\$)(?:.(?!\$\{))*?(\d+)/;
var str = 'there is a LaTex is ${ \\frac{123}{456} }$ and a pure number 789 and another LaTex ${ 9^{n+1} }$';
alert(str.match(regex)[1]);
```

Comment: maybe numbers like this `"number one 101,there is a LaTex is ${ \\frac{123}{456} }$ and a pure number 789 and another LaTex ${ 9^{n+1} }$ number last 202"`.i want match all this out of latex number.